# How to loop through an object array and output the array with a specific object property javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var obo = [{
        "parcelId": "009",
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    },
    {
        "parcelId": "009",
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    },
    {
        "parcelId": "009",
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    },
    {
        "parcelId": "009",
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    }, {
        "parcelId": "009",
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    }, {
        "parcelId": "009",
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    }
]
```

I want to loop through and return the array. i have tried splice its not working

```
var obo = [{
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    },
    {
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    },
    {
        "userid": "tomi",
        "location": "kwara"
    }
]
```

Am trying to populate the array so as not to have `parcelid` in it

Comment: What is your specific property, which property in the array are you looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.map()` with some object destructuring:

```js
var data = [
  {"parcelId": "009", "userid": "tomi", "location": "kwara"},
  {"parcelId": "009", "userid": "tomi", "location": "kwara"},
  {"parcelId": "009", "userid": "tomi", "location": "kwara"}
];

var result = data.map(({userid, location, ...rest}) => ({userid, location}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**References:**

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.map()`

```
obo = obo.map(function(item){
  return {
    userid: item.userid,
    location: item.location
  };
});
```

```js
var obo = [
  {
    "parcelId": "009",
    "userid": "tomi",
    "location": "kwara"
  },
  {
    "parcelId": "009",
    "userid": "tomi",
    "location": "kwara"
  },
  {
    "parcelId": "009",
    "userid": "tomi",
    "location": "kwara"
  }
];

obo = obo.map(function(item){
  return {
    userid: item.userid,
    location: item.location
  };
});
console.log(obo);
```

Comment: Since `delete` mutates original can do it in any loop. No real need to create new array using map() if using mutation approach

Answer (score 0):

How about that with `Array.prototype.map()`?

```js
var obo = [{
    "parcelId": "009",
    "userid": "tomi",
    "location": "kwara"
  },
  {
    "parcelId": "009",
    "userid": "tomi",
    "location": "kwara"
  },
  {
    "parcelId": "009",
    "userid": "tomi",
    "location": "kwara"
  }
]

var expected = [];

obo.map((elm, ind) => {
  expected.push({
    "userid": elm.userid,
    "location": elm.location
  })
})
console.log(expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
obo = obo.map(el => {
  let obj = {
    userid: el.userid,
    location: el.location
  };
  return obj;
});
```

or for a one liner, you can do this

`obo = obo.map(({userid,location})=>({userid,location})));`